# Xamarin forms shared project with images for Android and iOS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to upload an image inside the Shared project in my solution so that the Android and iOS project can use it normally via Xaml. Not working, I do not know why. Can anyone explain why it is not working?

Extension:

```
[ContentProperty("Source")]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{extensions:ImageResource MyProject.Assets.fechar.png}" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="16" Focused="Image_Focused" BackgroundColor="Red" WidthRequest="15" />
```

Putting a breakpoint in the Extension it usually goes there once for each item in my list.

I've also tried inserting a hardcoded binding by codebehind only for testing and it also does not work using ImageSource.FromResource.

The image file is as EmbbedResource as the documentation indicates.

Comment: can you show your project structure? Where this image is located? Is it Assets folder in Shared project?

Comment: I would suggest you to use embedded images if you dont need different sizes of images based on device. if you need different sizes, you need to use project specific folders. please read it here better and ask your question. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FromResource is referring to the Android or iOS project not the shared one. The images need to be in the appropriate folder of the platform specific project.

Comment: Okay, but what would be the proper method for using shared?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use extension. There is much easier way.

According to Xamarin "Currently there is no implicit conversion for resource identifiers, you must use ImageSource.FromResource" and "Because there is no built-in type converter from string to ResourceImageSource, these types of images cannot be natively loaded by Xaml". So you cannot specify in xaml that your image is shared but you can use code behind to bind a shared image.

In xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="80"/>
```

Then in code behind

```
public ImageSource Image
{
    get
    {
        return ImageSource.FromResource("ButtonRendererDemo.Resources.icon1.png"); //from PCL
    }
}
```

below is the project structure

[image]

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Tested with shared project. Below is the structure

[image]

The key is to add reference of your shared project to your PCL where you are calling FromResource. The shared project gets injected into PCL
Then in my project structure it is

```
public ImageSource Image
        {
            get
            {
                //return ImageSource.FromResource("ButtonRendererDemo.Resources.icon1.png"); //from PCL
                return ImageSource.FromResource("ButtonRendererDemo.Pictures.icon1.png"); //from Shared
            }
        }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

If nothing works for you use the follow code to find your resource. In the file where you call FromResource add using System.Reflection; then add the follow code

```
    var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
    }
```

You should see in Output window something like

found resource: someNamespace.Pictures.icon1.png - That's your resource you need to use.

You didn't answer my question about your project structure. Then I could give you an exact answer. I suspect that your path to image is "MyProject.Droid.Assets.fechar.png"